# Explain how the following is equal to $2\cos x$.

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

The question was

> Prove $$\frac{1+\sin2x+\cos2x}{\cos x+\sin x}=2\cos x$$

I simplified it using several trigonometric identities, what I got is this "$\dfrac{2\cos^2 x + 2\cos x \sin x}{\cos x + \sin x}$"

Please explain how can I get this to be to equal to $2\cos x $?

Comment: It seems you've already done the most difficult tasks. Keep up thinking and the answer will come easily.

Comment: Note also $2\cos^2 x = \cos^2 x + \cos^2 x = \cos^2 x+1-\sin^2 x$

Comment: To simplify any fraction, factor the numerator and denominator to see whether some factor in the numerator cancels some factor in the denominator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've done fine so far. Just factor out $2\cos x$ from the numerator:
$$2 \cos^2 x + 2 \cos x \sin x = 2\cos x(\cos x + \sin x)$$

With that as your numerator, simply cancel the common factor $(\cos x + \sin x)$ from numerator and denominator, leaving you with the desired $2\cos x$.